# MySQL Multiple Rows Same Table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table that holds rows of configuration data, ie:

```
id  item   value1  value2
2   class   ship    bow
3   class   car     tires
5   reg     ship    level1
7   reg     ship    level2
9   reg     car     level5
```

I am trying to create a query that selects all rows where item='class', and returns a data set that matches the initial query + all rows where item='reg' and value1=value1 (from initial results).

So in this scenario, the result set should look like:

```
class  ship  bow   reg   ship  level1
class  ship  bow   reg   ship  level2
class  car   tires reg   car   level5
```

I am a bit frustrated, and hope this makes sense.  Thanks for any pointers in the right direction!

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to do this stuff in code, not sql

Comment: @Toby Allen: True, but in this case the SQL is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to join the table to itself. Assuming your table is called `configs` (because you didn't tell us what it's called), something like this should work:

```
select t1.item, t1.value1, t1.value2, t2.item, t2.value1, t2.value2
    from configs as t1
    inner join configs as t2
    on t2.value1 = t1.value1 and t2.item = 'reg'
    where t1.item = 'class';
```

If you require all rows that have no matching `reg` row returned in the results as well, change `inner join` to `left outer join`. Make sure you have indexes on `item` and `value1` if you want this query to perform decently.

Here is a quick proof of concept that shows the query above works:

```
mysql> create table configs (
    -> id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    -> item varchar(32) not null,
    -> value1 varchar(32) not null,
    -> value2 varchar(32) not null,
    -> index (item),
    -> index (value1)
    -> ) engine=innodb charset=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into configs (id, item, value1, value2) values
    -> (2, 'class', 'ship', 'bow'),
    -> (3, 'class', 'car', 'tires'),
    -> (5, 'reg', 'ship', 'level1'),
    -> (7, 'reg', 'ship', 'level2'),
    -> (9, 'reg', 'car', 'level5');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from configs;
+----+-------+--------+--------+
| id | item  | value1 | value2 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+
|  2 | class | ship   | bow    |
|  3 | class | car    | tires  |
|  5 | reg   | ship   | level1 |
|  7 | reg   | ship   | level2 |
|  9 | reg   | car    | level5 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select t1.item, t1.value1, t1.value2, t2.item, t2.value1, t2.value2
    -> from configs as t1
    -> inner join configs as t2
    -> on t2.value1 = t1.value1 and t2.item = 'reg'
    -> where t1.item = 'class';
+-------+--------+--------+------+--------+--------+
| item  | value1 | value2 | item | value1 | value2 |
+-------+--------+--------+------+--------+--------+
| class | ship   | bow    | reg  | ship   | level1 |
| class | ship   | bow    | reg  | ship   | level2 |
| class | car    | tires  | reg  | car    | level5 |
+-------+--------+--------+------+--------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I think you have an error, as you are comparing t2.value1=t1.value1, as I think the on clause should be value1=item.

Comment: @JamesBlack: No. I got it right. Read the question again and look at his sample data. The `item` column only ever contains the values `class` and `reg`. The `value1` column is what he wants to match on.

Comment: Nicely detailed. I was able to test and implement in a very short time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  t2.*
FROM
  table t1
  LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.item = 'reg' AND t2.value1 = t1.value1
WHERE
  t1.item = 'class'
```

Comment: The select columns should be changed to match what was asked for in the question. Also, `table` is a SQL reserved word so you should surround it with backticks or change it to something else.

Comment: Answer was posted before the question was edited, I won't change it for clarity of an answer.

Comment: The only edits on the question were formatting. No content edits happened. You can [view the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9456891/revisions).

Comment: Agreed, before formatting example result set was the same and I haven't noticed that, yet to illustrate a way of selecting original result set plus additional result set from the same table, the answer is adequate.